# Convert SQL to LINQ with IN and MAX

Tags: sql, linq

How would I convert the SQL statement below into LINQ?

```
select
    kcustnum,
    (custsnum + 1),
    custartype,
    kcustsrch 
from
    custmast 
where
    kcustnum = 'cn' 
    and
    custsnum in (
        select
            max(custsnum)
        from
            custmast
        where
            kcustnum = 'cn'
    )
```

Comment: What is the schema of the `custmast` table? Can you explain the difference between `kcustnum` and `custsnum`?

Comment: This query can likely be rewritten without the `IN` subquery btw.

Comment: Thx Dai!  You were correct and Teo's syntax did the trick

Answer (score 0):

As @Dai mention you don't need `IN` since you use `MAX`.

What you're looking for:

```
var res = _context.custmast
                 .Where(x => x.kcustnum == "cn" 
                          && x.custsnum == _context.custmast
                                   .Where(y => y.kcustnum == 'cn')
                                   .Max(y => y.custsnum))
                 .Select(x => new 
                             {
                                x.kcustnum,
                                (x.custsnum + 1),
                                x.custartype,
                                x.kcustsrch 
                             });
```

this is my code that does not work:

```
    public ActionResult NameSelect(string customerNumber)
    {
        var shipto = from n in db.cs_Custmast
                      .Where(x => x.kcustnum == customerNumber
                      && x.custsnum == db.cs_Custmast
                               .Where(y => y.kcustnum == customerNumber)
                               .Max(y => y.custsnum))
                      .Select (n => new CustomersViewModel
                         {
                            Account = n.kcustnum,
                            Suffix = (n.custsnum + 1),
                            AccountType = n.custartype,
                            Search = n.kcustsrch 
                         });


        return View("_NameSelection", shipto);
    }
```

Comment: THX Teo!  This works.  I was trying it without the lamda's (cause they confuse the heck out of me) and getting no where.

Comment: Looks like I lied.  I still get an error that says "a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"